# Django - displaying images and image links

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am having problems getting images and image links to display.  I have a model method ('thumbnail_') that is supposed to display a thumbnail that is the link the the full size image.  It is not rendering to the webpage (image.html).  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

model.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    #tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    #albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #rating = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listings)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Save image dimensions
    super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    im = PImage.open(pjoin(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name))
    self.width, self.height = im.size

    # large thumbnail
    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image.name)
    im.thumbnail((256,256), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
    thumb_fn = fn + "-thumb2" + ext
    tf2 = NamedTemporaryFile()
    im.save(tf2.name, "JPEG")
    self.thumbnail2.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf2.name)), save=False)
    tf2.close()

    # small thumbnail
    im.thumbnail((60,60), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
    thumb_fn = fn + "-thumb" + ext
    tf = NamedTemporaryFile()
    im.save(tf.name, "JPEG")
    self.thumbnail.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf.name)), save=False)
    tf.close()

    super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


def size(self):
    # Image size #
    return "%s x %s" % (self.width, self.height)

def thumbnail_(self):
    return """<a href = "/media/%s"><img border="0" alt="" src="/media/%s" /></a>""" % (
                                                        (self.image.name, self.thumbnail.name))
thumbnail_.allow_tags = True

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.image.name
```

view.py

```
def image(request):
    image = Image.objects.values('id', 'title', 'thumbnail_')
    context = {
        'image' : image,
    }
    return render_to_response('bsmain/image.html', context)
```

image.html

```
<TABLE id="some_id">    
<TBODY>
    {% load humanize %}
    {% for row in image %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.title}}</td>
        <td>{{ row.thumbnail_}}</td>            
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</TBODY>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you get anything at all. This line in your view:

```
image = Image.objects.values('id', 'title', 'thumbnail_')
```

is not allowed, because `thumbnail_` is not a field, it is a method on the `Image` class. `values` operates only on fields, returning a queryset containing dicts of those names. Even if you used the actual field, `thumbnail`, in the `values` call, the template would still not output correctly, as the `thumbnail_` method does not exist on the dict that is returned by `values`.

The simple solution is to use a standard `Image.objects.all()` call here - trying to limit the number of fields returned is over-optimization.

(Also, please try and give your method a nicer name: something like `render_thumbnail` would be better than just `thumbnail_`.)

Comment: I changed method to render_thumbnail, and used Image.objects.all(). I also commented out ---- thumbnail_.allow_tags = True   and from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe, then changed my method to reflect "mark_safe"    return mark_safe("""<a href = "/media/%s"><img border="0" alt="" src="/media/%s" /></a>""" % (
                                                            (self.image.name, self.thumbnail.name)))

Comment: I now get tags that look like they should work but they are not rendering thumbnails or links.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any attribute named `thumbnail_`:

```
image = Image.objects.values('id', 'title', 'thumbnail_')
```

and

```
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
thumbnail2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
```

Check if the image is in correct directory.